# Joomla. VirtueMart. Не добавляется товар в корзину

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

При добавлении товара в корзину с главной страницы появляется белый экран. На других страницах данная проблема не наблюдается, только на главной. В чем может быть проблема?
Версия joomla: 3.6.5 Stable

P.S. заметил что поиск с главной тоже не работает, на других страницах работает.

Comment: Белый экран - это по всей вероятности php ошибка, включите Error reporting в админстративной части, Global configaration -> Server Settings -> Error Reporting и посмотрите какую ошибку показывает на белом экране

Comment: @Arsen, включил, все так же белый экран. Но в консоле есть ошибка: "HTTP ERROR 500". Как я понял ошибка сервера. Но почему-то не работает только на главной...

Comment: что ошибка 500 -  это понятно, у вас там какой то конфликт, но надо понять в каком файле данная проблема, а в корне сайта нет файла error.log ? там должны записываться все ошибки. Возможно ошибка в модуле корзины виртуемарт

Comment: @Arsen, файл логов пустой

Comment: @Arsen, А нет, спустя время появилась запись: `Fatal error: Call to private method VirtueMartCart::validateUserData() from context 'VirtueMartViewCart' in /plugins/system/onepage_generic/cart/view.html.php on line 547`

Comment: Строка: `$validUserDataBT = $cart->validateUserData();`